# Continuously monitor usb connection status

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I am facing a problem with usb port. when I connect a mobile device to my PC USB port, sometimes it becomes disconnect and immediately gets connected. So I want to monitor the USB connection status continuously. Is there any way I can monitor the connection status live?

It would be good if can get the log file also with only usb connection status

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with `pyudev` and a python script that monitors USB connections, logs the events to a file, and prints the events to the console.

start by installing the package`pip install pyudev`

then here is the script:

```
import os
import sys
import pyudev

from datetime import datetime

def log_event(event_type, device):
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    message = f"{timestamp} - {event_type}: {device.get('ID_SERIAL_SHORT') or device.get('ID_SERIAL')} - {device.get('ID_MODEL')}"

    with open("usb_connection_log.txt", "a") as log_file:
        log_file.write(message + "\n")

    print(message)

def monitor_usb_events():
    context = pyudev.Context()
    monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
    monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')

    for action, device in monitor:
        if action == 'add' and 'ID_SERIAL' in device:
            log_event("Connected", device)
        elif action == 'remove' and 'ID_SERIAL' in device:
            log_event("Disconnected", device)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        monitor_usb_events()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nMonitoring stopped.")
        sys.exit(0)
```